# nginx dynamic doute for laravel project use first param

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, dynamic, path

hi i am  a laravel developer. working at envato. i have some laravel  project . i would like to make a custom configuration for my laravel projects.

example

1. http://demo.jubayed.com/demo1/
2. http://demo.jubayed.com/demo2/
3. http://demo.jubayed.com/demo3/
4. http://demo.jubayed.com/demo4/
5. http://demo.jubayed.com/demo5/

   root demo.jubayed.com/$demoProject/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    server_name demo.jubayed.com;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /($demoProject)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        root /var/www/$demoProject/public;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /sitemap.xml { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
   # error_page 500 /index.php;
   # error_page 401 /index.php;
   # error_page 403 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `alias` instead of `root` as you need to manipulate the URI to insert `public` into the pathname. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

You will also need to use a nested `location` for PHP as it needs access to the same pathname.

```
location ~ ^/(?<project>[^/]+)/(?<suffix>.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/$project/public/$suffix;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /$project/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

I avoid using `try_files` and `alias` within the same block due to [long term issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.